# how to dynamically create multiple beans of same type then gather/autowire them

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

let's say that in my spring(boot) yaml config file I have a list of commands:

```
commands: [add,delete,copy,move]
```

and the corresponding class in my spring(boot) project:

```java
public class Command {

    private String name;

    public Command(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

How can I dynamically/adaptively generate the right number of command beans, then gather/autowire them in a separate class as below ?

```java
public class Menu {

   @Autowired
   List<Command> commands;

   public void display() {
       commands.forEach(cmd -> System.out.println(cmd.getName());
   }

}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your time and your expertise.

Regards

Comment: Do you need them loaded into the spring `ApplicationContext`?  There's nothing wrong with taking that property from the yaml into your `Menu` class and just creating the `Command` instances in there.

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic bean registration, you can use `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`.

The code will be like this:

```java
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata;

@Configuration
@Import(CommandsConfiguration.Registrar.class)
public class CommandsConfiguration {

    static class Registrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

        @Override
        public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
            final List<String> commands = // read commands from environemnt/config
            for (String command : commands) {
                final String beanName = command + "Command";
                final BeanDefinition beanDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                    .genericBeanDefinition(Command.class, () -> new Command(command))
                    .getBeanDefinition();
                registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
            }
        }
    }
}
```